# Recently active for intags:mine says last activity was modified ... for everything

Tags: bug, tags, search, last-activity

If I do a search with `intags:mine is:q`, every single result says that the last activity was a modification.

[image: intags "modified 2 mins ago"]

If I search by a particular tag, however, they show up correctly.

[image: python "answered 2 mins ago"]

Comment: Those are two different pages - if you only search for a tag, we redirect you to the question list for that tag. Search results aren't aware of last activity if I recall at all, so this is more of a feature request than a bug report.

Comment: Point being, this may be by design. :) I'll have to double-check what sort of information we track in the search index and whether this change is possible in the first place without re-indexing the entirety of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AdamLear: If they aren't aware of the last activity, why did it get the amount of time correct? I don't believe I answered the question within a minute of it being asked, so I wouldn't expect it to say `modified 2 mins ago`; it would be more like `modified 5 mins ago`.  Besides that, if it doesn't know the last activity, shouldn't it say `asked 2 mins ago`, not `modified 2 mins ago`?

Comment: We index the time and the author of the last change, but not the type. All other tabs on the results page say "asked". Activity is sorted by, well, activity which could be edits, answers, etc, so we use a generic term "modified" there instead.

Comment: @AdamLear: That makes sense, but wouldn't "active" be better?  "Modified" is used already to mean something else.

Comment: "modified" is what we used to say everywhere (including the question lists on the site) before we started tracking more specific actions ("edited", "answered", etc) a couple years ago. It's still the default term we use.